# Стилизовать HTML тег output

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, подсветка-синтаксиса

Зачастую когда пишешь ответ приходится писать вывод кода вручную, так как компилятов в SO нет. Я предлагаю стилизовать этот тег как обычный тег `<pre>` или `<code>` только без подсветки синтаксиса. Почему? Сейчас покажу:

```
Non-sorted
1
3
2
5
4
Sorted
1
2
3
4
5
```

Видны попытки подсветки синтаксиса, но они только сбивают с толку. Хотелось чтобы текст был черным полностью.

Comment: я не понял о каком теге output идет речь, если в твоем примере ты его не используешь

Comment: Это неправильный пример а вообще http://htmlbook.ru/html/output

Comment: А можете отметить, пожалуйста, [ответ Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7133/220571) как принятый или прокомментируйте, почему именно он вам не подходит.

Answer (score 17):

Подсветка синтаксиса появляется так как используемый плагин пытается угадать на каком языке этот блок кода. Чтобы убрать подсветку достаточно воспользоваться подсказкой `lang-none`, которая прямо указывает [не использовать никакую подсветку](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/282647)

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

Например:

```
Non-sorted
1
3
2
5
4
Sorted
1
2
3
4
5
```